# props.history.push inside functional component renders doesn't render the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm using the context API and inside my AuthContextProvider I have a function that I call and then changes the route;problem is it changes the route but does not render the component and I have no idea why. I believe if I converted my auth-context.js class to a class based one it would work.

I tried return `Redirect to ="/ />` but that does not work. 
 I'm stumped.I'd love if someone could help out

```
auth-context.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
export const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  isAuth: false,
  login: () => {},
  seedFirebase: () => {}
});

const AuthContextProvider = props => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  console.log(props);
  const loginHandler = () => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    props.history.push('/'); //this changes the route but does not render the component
  };
  //THIS FUNCTION SEEDS THE FIREBASE DATABASE
  const seedDb = () => {
    const data = {
      items: 'Folders'
    };
    // axios.post('/items.json', data).then(resp => console.log(resp.data));
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        login: loginHandler,
        isAuth: isAuthenticated,
        seedFirebase: seedDb
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default withRouter(AuthContextProvider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this incase anyone else has this peculiar issue. I solved this issue using the following logic: I check in the component that's calling the login function, if the `isAuthenticated` is true I redirect to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is that create a history.js file inside a helper folder in the source directory.
Add the following code inside the history.js file.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then import the history.js file into the following file you need.

```
import history from '/helpers/history';
```

Then use `history.push('/')` to redirect to the home component.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi thanks for the response unfortunately it's still the same issue - it changes the route but the component never gets rendered

Comment: <Router history={history}>
 <Switch>
  <Route
   exact={true}
   path={'/'}
   component={yourHomeComponent} />
 </Switch>
</Router>
Have you added the route in App.js like this?